# create physical volume from multipath raid system

Tags: mount, raid, multipath-storage

I currently want to mount an existing raid system. The rack is connected via multipath. With the command `multipath -ll` all racks are correctly shown and the mapper are present under `/dev`.

My first attempt was to create a physical volume from the mapper

```
pvcreate /dev/mapper/raid
```

However I got an unexpected return:

```
  Can't initialize physical volume "/dev/mapper/raid" of volume group "vgRAID" without -ff
  /dev/mapper/raid: physical volume not initialized.
```

Am I missing something? It seems that volume group already exist. But as far as I remember I had to first create physical, then group and finally logical volumes. I don't want to use `-ff` as I doubt it will overwrite my filesystem.

Comment: is it listed in `blkid`, `lsblk`, `pvs`, `vgs`, `lvs`, ...?

Comment: What does `vgs -o +devices` show?

Comment: `blkid` and `lsblk` show both the UUIDs of the mapper and the isolated drives for example `/dev/sda` `/dev/sdb` `/dev/sdc` etc. which ware part of the mapper. `pvs` `vgs` and `lvs` do not show the raid volumes yes

Comment: `vgs -o +devices` return the same as `vgs`

Comment: I think I have to `vgexport` the raid on the current system before using them on the new one

Answer (score 2):

The problem was on rocky linux the logical volume manager do not reconize all volumes by default. They have to be adressed using:

```
$ lvmdevices --adddev /dev/md0
$ vgchange -ay vg-datastore
```

then they are present using `pvs` and `vgs`